# Why set automatically unpacks range, but list doesn`t? How this can be used?

Tags: python, list, set, range

I create list and set with range. Set unpacks range, list doesn`t

```
>>> my_list = [range(5)]
>>> my_set = set(range(5))
>>> my_list
[range(0, 5)]
>>> my_set
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> my_list = [*range(5)]
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't unpack is because `my_list` is only putting two brackets next to it, if you do that with set it will be the same:

```
>>> my_set = {range(5)}
{range(0, 5)}
```

But if you do `list(...)` it will unpack:

```
>>> my_set = list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are explicitly creating a new object with `range(5)` as an argument. This can be done with lists too.

```py
>>> my_list = list(range(5))
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In this piece of your code:

```py
>>> my_list = [range(5)]
```

You are creating a list with one generator as its only value. Remember, Python is a first class language, which makes it possible to do this. You can also do this with a set:

```py
>>> my_set = {range(5)}
>>> my_set
{range(0, 5)}
```

Answer (score 2):

range function returns class

```
type(range(5))
<class 'range'>
```

you are building a list of range objects.if you define

```
foo = {range(5)}
```

it will be the set of range objects.

You should do the same for both to got the same behavior

```
foo = list(range(5))
bar = set(range(5))
```